# How to build a Choropleth map in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, choropleth

So I'm trying to make a Choropleth map of Spain in React, using leaflet. This is my code: `

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, GeoJSON, FeatureGroup } from 'react-leaflet';
import OSMProvider from './OSM-provider';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import spainGeoJSON from '../sources/spainregions.geojson';
import L from 'leaflet';



const SpainMap = () => {
  const [geoJSONData, setGeoJSONData] = useState(null);
  const mapRef = useRef();
  const ZOOM_LEVEL = 6;
  const [center, setCenter] = useState({ lat: 40.4165000, lng: -3.7025600 });


  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col text-center">
        <div className="col">
          <MapContainer center={center} zoom={ZOOM_LEVEL} whenCreated={setCenter} ref={mapRef}>
            <TileLayer url={OSMProvider.maptiler.url} attribution={OSMProvider.maptiler.attribution} />
            <FeatureGroup>
              {geoJSONData && (
                <GeoJSON data={geoJSONData.features}/>
              )}
            </FeatureGroup>
          </MapContainer>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SpainMap;
```

As you can see, is a simple map component. For some reason I don't understand, the geojson part is not displaying, and I only see the map when I look at it in the app, but no polygons drawn. Someone sees the problem here? I watched several tutorials and I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

Also, this is the format of my geojson file:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "5603",
            "properties": {
                "name": "A Coruña",
                "density": 0,
                "path": "/world/Spain/A Coruña"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [
                                -7.680295,
                                43.787137
                            ],
                            [
                                -7.66231,
                                43.774811
                            ], (and go on...)
```

I tried to change how I import the geojson file several times, also I tried to check in an online geojson validator and everything was okey. For example, in this page: http://geojson.io/ when I upload my file, it displays the regions as I want.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but for drawing multipolygons I think is right. Also because I check in the validator for multipolygon geojson and it says is right. Here: https://www.itb.ec.europa.eu/json/geojson/upload

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using fetch. Still I don't understand why I need to use fetch function if I already imported my file, if someone would answer that, that'd be great.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, GeoJSON, FeatureGroup } from 'react-leaflet';
import OSMProvider from './OSM-provider';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import spainGeoJSON from '../sources/spainregions.geojson';

const SpainMap = () => {
  const [geoJSON, setGeoJSON] = useState(null);
  const mapRef = useRef();
  const ZOOM_LEVEL = 6;
  const center = { lat: 40.4165000, lng: -3.7025600 };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch the GeoJSON data
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(spainGeoJSON);
        const data = await response.json();
        setGeoJSON(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching GeoJSON data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col text-center">
        <div className="col">
          <MapContainer center={center} zoom={ZOOM_LEVEL} ref={mapRef}>
            <TileLayer url={OSMProvider.maptiler.url} attribution={OSMProvider.maptiler.attribution} />
            <FeatureGroup>
              {geoJSON && <GeoJSON data={geoJSON} />}
            </FeatureGroup>
          </MapContainer>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SpainMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use fetch because that is the only way you can parse/convert JSON data to a javascript object.

I hope it helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).